# Eclipse juno doesnot show NDK option (windows )

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have downloaded eclipse bundle pack from official site of android, i want to specify the path of ndk but i didnot find any option, here is the screenshot

[image]

i find a answer and reinstall adt but still i am not getting option of NDK and now whenever i tried to reinstall the adt i am getting error

[image]

How to define path of ndk ???

Comment: Have you tried to remove the ADT before re-installing? I suggest that you download the plugin [ADT-23.0.3.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.3.zip) from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: I have done the same, but no use and i am using ADT 23.0.3 so i think there must be issue with eclipse juno itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand whats the issue with eclipse juno, but i ended up downloading new version of eclipse this time i have downloaded eclipse_luna and install the same adt that i have tried with eclipse juno previously, and everything is working fine.